# Is it necessary to update Android apps?

Tags: applications, updates, performance

Recently I got a new Android smartphone and I want to know if it's necessary to update Android apps frequently. The reason for asking this is

1. Does updating Android apps reduce battery usage?
2. Should I update my apps if I don't have much internal memory? Will it slow down my phone if there isn't enough internal memory?
3. Will there be any (real) performance improvement if we update apps?

I know that certain updates provide new features, bug fixes (I hope it means errors), and changes in the background/layout.

Without considering the added feature, bug fixes, and layout, is it necessary to update? Also, each update takes a good amount of internal memory in my phone as well as a lot of valuable mobile data.

Comment: 1) maybe, depends on the update. 2) probably, but the low memory itself will impact the performance whether you update it or not 3) maybe, depends on the update. Certain update does mention "*improve performance*". In the end, it's up to the user to update or not, but if possible, update.

Comment: Just to add to your question: Some apps refuse to work, if you don't have the latest version installed, so updating is necessary for them to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Mobile Data for update purposes, then it is better to update Google services and the messaging services only, but if you have access to WiFi then keep your apps updated.

1. Battery Optimization: There's a reason developers constantly update apps, and most of the time it's memory or battery optimization. Keeping your apps updated also means you have the best optimizations available. Likewise, delete old apps you no longer use, because these may be running background processes that chew up RAM and battery life.
2. Memory: The updated apps generally use memory efficiently in most of cases, though I don't think there would be much impact due to it. You can clear the caches or use softwares like 360 Security or Turbo Cleaner for that purpose.
3. Performance: Not always, but most of the time there is a improvement.

Stability: New versions of software also fix other, non-security-related bugs. For example, a new version could solve crashes you may be experiencing or make a feature work properly.

Comment: Just to know,did you ever feel an improvement in battery life by updating apps.And a question that pesters me is while updating most of the updates have a size equivalent to previous version of the app or greater.In that case if i am right what happens on updating apps  is that the previous  version is deleted and newer one is installed.Right?Or is it that new data is being added to the previous version (of course not.This would be dumb to ask but still) like updating antivirus applications on pc (where virus signatures are added to the previous one).

Comment: I'd avoid using memory booster apps. From my personal experience these apps(on low end devices)provide more of a mirage in terms of actually doing the job of cleaning RAM memory. They hog a lot of space limiting other apps. On high end devices sure, cause memory is plenty to go around but for standard devices not really

Comment: Also i updated all my apps.And it took 1gb of my internal storage.But that is a great amount.In that case after updating all these apps approximately 20 times  my phones internal would be left with nothing.....